# Is there a way to count the number of triggered alerts in a period and visualize it in a dashboard?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I created alerts in GCP Monitoring and would like to count the number of alerts that got triggered and visualize it in a dashboard. Is there some sort of metric for that?

If this is not possible with a metric, is there some other way to count the number of Monitoring alerts that happen in a period of time like 1 hour or 1 day?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to uptime checks [1], you can create dashboards [2] using the Cloud Monitoring `uptime_check/check_passed` metric as the basis for a chart that displays the status of an uptime check, and view the number of passed/failed checks [3] for the period you chose.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks

[2] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/uptime-charts

[3] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks#get